# Dynamically add formControl when generated in template

Tags: angular, typescript, django-rest-framework, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm making an app that gets a set of questions and answers gathered from a real world demographics survey stored in a django REST API backend. I have divided the survey into components based on the surveys question categories (i.e. questions that pertain to health, demographics, income etc). Specific proposed answers to a question have unique IDs that point back to the question id and the survey id, they also have a "type" property that indicates if the answer asks for an amount, text etc. The parent "Survey" component has child "Category" components that inherit the parent "FormGroup" via @Input.

**salud.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="encuestaHogarForm" class="container">
    <!-- primary questions -->
  <div *ngFor="let textoPregunta of preguntasUnicas; let i = index">
    <h3 id="label{{i}}">{{textoPregunta}}</h3>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let p of preguntas">
      <ng-container *ngIf="textoPregunta === p.preguntaxencuesta.pregunta.texto_pregunta">
        <!-- primary answers that belong to a question -->
        <span [ngSwitch]="p.tipo">
          <p *ngSwitchCase="'B'">
            <mat-radio-button name="rbRes{{p.preguntaxencuesta.id}}" aria-labelledby="label{{i}}"
              formControlName="valorRP{{p.id}}">{{p.respuesta_propuesta.texto_respuesta}}</mat-radio-button>
          </p>
          <p *ngSwitchCase="'C'">

          </p>
          <!-- secondary questions that belong to a primary question-answer -->
          <ng-container *ngFor="let p2 of preguntasSecundarias"> 
            <ng-container *ngIf="p2.preguntasecundariaxresp.preguntaxencuestaxrespuesta.id === p.id">
              <mat-form-field *ngIf="p2.tipo === 'C'">
                <input matInput placeholder="{{p2.preguntasecundariaxresp.pregunta_secundaria.texto_pregunta}}">
              </mat-form-field>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </span>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
</form>
```

I wish to assign a `formControlName` to the dynamically generated `mat-radio-button` to be able to add it to my `encuestaHogarForm` parent form. I have considered the use of a `FormArray` but I don't know how to dynamically push elements as they are created in the DOM into the `FormArray`.

I tried assigning the `formControlName="valorRP{{p.id}}"` The same way in my component.ts

**salud.component.ts**

```
...

getPreguntas(): void {
    this.encuestaService.getPreguntasPrimariasPorCategoria(this.categoria)
      .subscribe(preguntas => {
        this.preguntas = preguntas;
        this.preguntasUnicas = [...new Set(preguntas.map(array => array.preguntaxencuesta.pregunta.texto_pregunta))];
        this.preguntasUnicas.forEach(textoPregunta => {
          this.preguntas.forEach(p => {
            if (textoPregunta === p.preguntaxencuesta.pregunta.texto_pregunta) {
              this.encuestaHogarForm.addControl('valorRP' + p.id, new FormControl()); // Attempts to register the controls
              this.preguntasSecundarias.forEach(p2 => {
                if (p2.preguntasecundariaxresp.preguntaxencuestaxrespuesta.url === p.url) {
                  //console.log('- ' + p2.preguntasecundariaxresp.pregunta_secundaria.texto_pregunta);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        });
      });
  }

...
```

However this doesn't work as intended because I assume it is attempting to find the `formControlName` in the DOM before it is created

Answer (score 1):

Jose, be sure you're initizle the formGroup

```
encuestaHogarForm=new FormGroup({})
```

MoreOver, you can also iterate over encuestaHogarForm.controls |keyvalue  NOT over preguntasUnicas,e.g. simple in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fncaig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div *ngFor="let control of myForm.controls|keyvalue;let i=index" >
    {{questions[i]}}
       <input [formControl]="myForm.get('valorRP'+i)">
  </div>
</form>

  myForm=new FormGroup({})
  questions=["uno","dos","tres","cuatro"]
  add()
  {
    const index=Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).length
    this.myForm.addControl('valorRP'+index,new FormControl(null))
  }
```